# What is the best UI design for picking object icon in Android?

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` which provides UI for editing entity properties such as name, description an so on. This entity can also have an icon but (this is the main problem) can have no icon. I have created an icon picker activity which provides UI for icon selection. But I can not think of a simple and pretty way to provide access to this picker from parent activity. It could be a simple image button if the task was just to select an icon but I have also to make it possible to remove already set icon. Having two buttons with 'choose' and 'remove' seems ugly. Any smart ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've ended with ImageButton showing selected icon or special 'No' icon if object has no icon. On button click I show `PopupMenu` on 3.0+ and `ContextMenu` on older versions. Menu contains 'Change' and 'Remove' items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a border that surrounds an empty space or the image if there is one already.

If the image exists, clicking on it brings up a dialog where you can choose to change it or remove it.

If it doesn't exist, clicking on it brings up a dialog where you can add it.

Answer (score 0):

how about a `gridview` within a `custom dialog` fired from your parent activity??
change the icon `onItemSelected()` of the gridview??